# SELECT hanging with SOS_SCHEDULER_YIELD lastwaittype

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, select-query

I've been experiencing a strange situation with a specific `SELECT` on SQL Server 2008 Standard.

I have a proc that executes a bunch of commands.

One of the last tasks is to insert the result of a select statement into a table. This proc is executed for each step of a job (with 20 steps) just changing one parameter, store code (the company has 20 stores).

This insert-select command normally executes in 2 minutes, but sometimes, it gets stuck with an `SOS_SCHEDULER_YIELD` lastwaittype and hangs forever... until I kill the process. After that, if I execute the same command, it executes in the normal 2 minutes.

I noticed that it doesn't matter if the CPU has 99% usage or 1%, or if there are other processes executing at the same time. I didn't find any pattern with these events. It just happens sometimes (almost every day with one or two steps).

Has anyone experienced this? I don't know what to do; I made a job to kill the process and execute it again if it hangs in `SOS_SCHEDULER_YIELD` for a long time, but I'd like to have a solution.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow , Please before you post a question be sure that you read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You've done some [research](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/identifying-queries-with-sos_scheduler_yield-waits)?

Comment: Yes, I have already read this post, but didn't help me with the problem...

Comment: Anyone? I'm still facing it